# Using Math.max and Math.min to remove highest and lowest number from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need to remove the highest and lowest numbers from the array and sum the remaining numbers together. (duplicate values can stay e.g. [2, 2, 3, 5, 8] just removes the 2 once.)

Created 2 separate min and max values and then subtracted them from total of array.

Also should return 0 when array is empty?

Passes a few tests but cannot see why it does not pass all of the criteria specified above?

```
function sumArray(array)
{
  var sum = 0;

  var min = Math.min(...array);  // lowest in array by spreading
  var max = Math.max(...array);  // highest in array by spreading

  if(array === null)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
  {
    (sum += array[i]);  
  }
  return ((sum - max) - min);
}
```

Comment: Which criteria it does not pass, actually?

Comment: If either the largest or smallest values appear more than once in the array your code won't work. You should compare `array[i]` to both `min` and `max` and only add it to `sum` if it is neither of those values.

Comment: Obviously you can us any form of brace placement and indentation you want in your code, but ***please*** don't use the style above when asking for help. (I'm advise strenuously not using it even when not asking for help.) Putting the ending `}` on the end of the last line in the block makes it hard to read and makes it hard to move code around. [Here's your code in a fairly standard style](https://pastebin.com/7uZRq9n0).

Comment: ^^ should be the styling guide for answers as well ...

Comment: @NinaScholz - Yeah. Somebody, somewhere, is popularizing this horrible style. I wish I knew who it was so we could Have A Talk. It seems to be someone who has influence over new coders, which just makes it worse.

Comment: array have only positives values, and integer values?

Comment: btw, to much parentheses, one around the assignment and around the return expression. both works without. the last one because the order remains from start to end, because all operators shares the same precedence.

Comment: ok I have a lot to learn and refine then!! thanks all

Comment: @TheWitness passes almost every array type but fails occasionally when it expects 0 but gets NaN.

Comment: @Tony, do you have an example of array that fails?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one thing, **if** you need this check:

```
if(array === null){
return 0;}
```

...you need it **before** the code above it using `array`.

Also, you shouldn't include the `min` and `max` values in the `sum` in the first place. You can't just subtract them — after all, a value may appear *more than once* in the array. (Your code will have the wrong result for `[2, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, for instance, because it counts `2` twice but only subtracts it once.) So instead of subtracting them after the fact, just don't *add* them in the loop in the first place.

Comment: Regarding duplicate max and/or min values, one could argue that the requirements are unclear in this case.

Comment: @JackA. - Maybe. To me *"Need to remove the highest and lowest numbers from the array and sum the remaining numbers together."* is fairly clear, but if I were writing an assignment, I would make it *unambiguous*. :-) In school I was forever taking test papers up to the teacher and saying "About question 27...do you mean X or Y?" because of things like that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) would be a simpler way to sum your array up

```js
function sumArray(array) {
  // Nothing to do so we retrun zero
  if(!Array.isArray(array) || array.length == 0) return 0;
  
  var min = Math.min(...array);  // lowest in array by spreading
  var max = Math.max(...array);  // highest in array by spreading

  // Sum up the numbers in the array
  var sum = array.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);

  // Do the math
  return sum - max - min;
}

console.log(sumArray([2, 2, 3, 5, 8]))
console.log(sumArray())
console.log(sumArray([]))
console.log(sumArray([0]))
console.log(sumArray([null, 0, 12]))
console.log(sumArray([null]))
```

Comment: ok will have to learn this now! have never come across this before. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, I am not supposed to show this ?

*(because there are so many here who can do this same answer)*

```js
function sumArray(array)
{
  if (array === null) return 0
  
  let sum = array.reduce((a,c)=>a+c) // sum array values
    , min = Math.min(...array)      // lowest in array by spreading
    , max = Math.max(...array)     // highest in array by spreading

  console.log({sum,min,max})

  return (sum - max - min)
}


console.log('sumArray',sumArray([2, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your code does not meet the criteria if the array has a length of 1. Only one value can be removed then and the sum of the remaining ones is `0`, but you are in fact subtracting it twice.

Also in the case of the empty array, `max()` and `min()` will return `-Infinity` and `Infinity` respectively, which do sum to `NaN` not to `0`. Your `=== null` check doesn't test for an empty array (`[]`, with a `.length` of `0`), but for a non-existing array.

So to deal with those issues, I would write

```
function sumArray(array) {
  if (array.length <= 2) return 0;

  const min = Math.min(...array);
  const max = Math.max(...array);

  const sum = array.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0);

  return sum - max - min;
}
```

If your function is supposed to also work with non-array values such as `null` and return `0` for them, add a second check:

```
  if (!Array.isArray(array) || array.length <= 2) return 0;
```

Comment: Might want to make sure `array` is an array

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I thought of that, but really what the OP described was a function always getting an Array of numbers. I normally try not to clutter my functions with defensiveness, it makes code harder to read.

Comment: After typing TypeScript, I have become accustomed to doing all those types of checks which is why I have been doing it.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Sure, with typescript we'd make our assumption explicit and checkable. But where to stop? Do we also need to check `array.every(Number.isFinite)` etc?

Comment: If we were building a public npm package than i guess maybe but otherwise probably don't have to go to overboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array and remove the first and last value instead of identifying max and min values individually.

You can also wrap `null` in an array to avoid creating special cases for in the execution flow:

```js
const sumArray = arr =>
  (arr || Array.of(arr))
 .sort((a, b) => a - b)
 .slice(1, (arr && (arr.length - 1)))
 .reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0)

console.log(sumArray([2, 2, 3, 5, 8]))
console.log(sumArray(null))
console.log(sumArray([]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for null instead of an empty array ([]) in your if statement. To check for an empty array, you can use the length property:

```
    if (array.length === 0) {
      return 0;
    }
```

When there are duplicate highest or lowest numbers, your code subtracts them twice. To fix this, you can remove the highest and lowest values using the splice() method, and then sum the remaining numbers.

```
function sumArray(array) {
      if (array.length === 0) {
        return 0;
      }
  
      var min = Math.min(...array);
      var max = Math.max(...array);
  
      var minIndex = array.indexOf(min);
      var maxIndex = array.indexOf(max);
  
      if (minIndex > -1) {
        array.splice(minIndex, 1);
      }
  
      if (maxIndex > -1) {
        array.splice(maxIndex, 1);
      }
  
      var sum = 0;
  
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
      }
  
      return sum;
    }
```